# Relative risk multivariate regression error

Tags: r, regression

I'm trying to do relative risk multivariate regression but I obtain an error and I don't understand How to solve the problem.

here's the code:

```
fit.glm <- glm(RemDAS ~     Sex + Age    , data = db,family=binomial())

fit.logbin <- logbin(formula(fit.glm), data = db)
coef(summary(fit.logbin))[,'Pr(>|z|)']
exp(coef(fit.logbin))
exp(confint(fit.logbin))
```

My data:

```
> db$RemDAS
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0
[61] 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1
Levels: 0 1
> db$Sex
 [1] 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
[61] 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1
Levels: 0 1
> db$Age
 [1] 68 35 40 41 63 46 65 65 49 54 85 65 39 61 55 62 21 46 58 49 71 46 37 31 59 49 62 52 71 34 62 59 65 58 74 58 48 51 76 53
[41] 53 28 77 55 50 42 55 48 32 36 40 41 51 64 54 58 20 67 70 52 53 58 49 42 58 48 43 60 77 69 49 60 38 73 45 72 46 60 39 47
[81] 59 58 51 47 67 71 37 74 46
>
```

The errors I obtain:

```
> fit.logbin <- logbin(formula(fit.glm), data = db)
Warning message:
nplbin: fitted probabilities numerically 1 occurred 
> 
> coef(summary(fit.logbin))[,'Pr(>|z|)']
(Intercept)        Sex1         Age 
        NaN         NaN         NaN 
Warning message:
MLE on boundary of parameter space, cannot use asymptotic covariance matrix 
> 
> exp(coef(fit.logbin))
(Intercept)        Sex1         Age 
  1.0640070   1.1193059   0.9913005 
> exp(confint(fit.logbin))
            2.5 % 97.5 %
(Intercept)   NaN    NaN
Sex1          NaN    NaN
Age           NaN    NaN
Warning message:
MLE on boundary of parameter space, cannot use asymptotic covariance matrix
```

Comment: With your `glm` call you were doing logistic regression, not relative risk regression, and there is no `logbin` function in the suite of base packages. Furthermore, none of those messages are errors, but it would appear that your first warning signified a failure to calculate a variance-covariance matrix and that causes the rest of you code to fail.

Comment: The fundamental mathematical problem is that you have many `0` outcomes and an attempt to use a log link blows up.

Comment: How can I perform a relative risk regression? Thank you